# In general does lim |f(x,y)| = |lim f(x,y)|?

Tags: calculus, limits, continuity

I understand that for any continuous functions f and g, the following holds:

$$\lim_{x \rightarrow a} f(g(x)) = f(\lim_{x \rightarrow a} g(x))$$

For this purpose of evaluating limits, is the absolute function considered to be continuous? ie. does this hold in general:

$$\lim_{x \rightarrow a} |g(x)| = |\lim_{x \rightarrow a} g(x)|$$

Comment: It holds in general if both limits exist, for the reason you gave: the absolute value function is continuous. For an example where only one of the limits exists, take $g(x) = -1$ for $x < 0$ and $g(x) = 1$ for $x \geq 0$. Then $\lim_{x \to 0}|g(x)| = 1$ but $\lim_{x \to 0} g(x)$ does not exist and so $|\lim_{x \to 0} g(x)|$ also does not exist.

Comment: If $g$ is continuous at $a$ and $f$ is continuous at $b = g(a)$, then $$\lim_{x \to a} f\bigl(g(x)\bigr) = f\bigl(\lim_{x \to a} g(x)\bigr) = f\bigl(g(a)\bigr).$$(This is true in great generality; particularly, if $a$ and/or $b$ are vectors.) Incidentally, the title and the two questions in the body don't match. It would be helpful if you aligned things so it's clear for posterity exactly what you're asking. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the absolute value function $|\cdot|\colon \mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ is a continuous function. In particular, your stated equation is true for continuous $g$.

Comment: sorry to clarify - does my first statement hold in the circumstance that A) f is continuous, or that B) g is continuous, or does it require that C) both f and g are continuous?>

Comment: Your first statement holds if both $f$ and $g$ are continuous.

To see the necessity of the continuity of $g$, take $g$ to be the function that is $0$ on the negative reals and $1$ on the nonnegative reals, and take $f$ to be the constant $0$ function. Then the limit on the right is $0$ for all $a$ but the expression on the right isn't even defined for $a = 0$.

To see the necessity of the continuity of $f$, take $f$ to be what $g$ was in the previous paragraph, and $g$ to be the identity. Then the expression on the left isn't defined for $a = 0$, but the right is $1$ for $a = 0$.

Comment: Thanks I amended the question.